# Gotta catch 'em all!

Tags: c#, json, community-challenge, pokemon

[This week's challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1281/23788) is essentially about fetching Json data from the Web, and deserializing it into objects. I don't have much time to devote to this one, so what I have is very basic: it displays the names of all pokemons in a WPF ListView:

[image: there's pikachu!]

Here's the code for the window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var service = new PokemonApp.Web.Pokedex();
        var pokemons = service.SelectAllPokemonReferences().OrderBy(pokemon => pokemon.Name);
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel { References = pokemons };
    }
}
```

As you've guessed, the interesting code is in the `Pokedex` class:

```
public class Pokedex
{
    public IEnumerable<ResourceReference> SelectAllPokemonReferences()
    {
        string jsonResult = GetJsonResult(PokeDexResultBase.BaseUrl + "pokedex/1/");

        dynamic pokemonRefs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResult);
        ICollection<ResourceReference> references = new List<ResourceReference>();

        foreach (var pokeRef in pokemonRefs.pokemon)
        {
            string uri = PokeDexResultBase.BaseUrl + pokeRef.resource_uri.ToString();
            references.Add(new ResourceReference
                            {
                                Name = pokeRef.name,
                                ResourceUri = new Uri(uri)
                            });
        }

        return references;
    }

    private static string GetJsonResult(string url)
    {
        string result;

        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        try
        {
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            result = string.Empty;
            // throw?
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The `ResourceReference` class has nothing special:

```
public class ResourceReference
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri ResourceUri { get; set; }
}
```

---

This quite basic code makes a foundation for the more complex objects:

```
public abstract class PokeDexResultBase : IPokeDexUri
{
    private readonly string _controller;
    protected PokeDexResultBase(string controller)
    {
        _controller = string.IsNullOrEmpty(controller) ? BaseUrl : controller;
    }

    public static string BaseUrl { get { return "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/"; } }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Uri ResourceUri { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

    public virtual string Url { get { return BaseUrl + _controller + (Id == 0 ? string.Empty : Id.ToString()); } }
}
```

That base class is inherited by everything that has an `Id` in the API:

```
public class Pokemon : PokeDexResultBase
{
    public Pokemon() : base("pokemon/") { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ResourceReference> Abilities { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ResourceReference> EggGroups { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PokemonEvolution> Evolutions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PokemonMove> Moves { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PokemonType> Types { get; set; }
    public int Attack { get; set; }
    public int CatchRate { get; set; }
    public int Defense { get; set; }
    public int EggCycles { get; set; }
    public string EvolutionYield { get; set; }
    public int ExperienceYield { get; set; }
    public string GrowthRate { get; set; }
    public int Happiness { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public int HitPoints { get; set; }
    public string MaleFemaleRatio { get; set; }
    public int SpecialAttack { get; set; }
    public int SpecialDefense { get; set; }
    public string Species { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }
}

public class PokemonEvolution
{
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public Uri ResourceUri { get; set; }
    public string ToPokemonName { get; set; }
}
```

There are other classes involved, but there's nothing much to review about them, they're very similar to the `Pokemon` class.

As I extend my code I'll add more methods to the `Pokedex` class, which will use the `GetJsonResult` method.

Have I well analyzed the API - I mean, is this code a solid foundation for deserializing pokemons and eventually getting them to fight against each other? What could be done better? Any nitpicks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a class such as `ResourceReference` makes sense as far as wrapping the API is concerned, from a UI standpoint, it's like using POCO's in the UI layer: If the data came from a database through Entity Framework, this code would be displaying the entities. This is a basic implementation, but if the goal is to make it an extensible "skeleton" implementation, there should be a *ViewModel* class for the UI to display, independently of the WebAPI-provided objects; the *ViewModel* doesn't care about `ResourceUri` - this property isn't meant to be displayed, it's plumbing for querying the API, doesn't belong in the UI.

As far as the `Pokedex` service class goes, it looks like it could work, however it should be returning *ViewModel* objects for the UI to consume, and the static `GetJsonResult` method could be encapsulated in its own class, which would be an HTTP-based implementation of a helper object whose role is to fetch the data - there could be a SqlServer-based implementation that would do the same thing off a database, idea being to decouple the *data* from its *data source*... but it could be overkill.

Usage of `Uri` in the POCO classes adds unnecessary complexity: they could just as well be kept as normal strings, so this code:

> ```
> string uri = PokeDexResultBase.BaseUrl + pokeRef.resource_uri.ToString();
> ```

Could then look like this, skipping the useless `.ToString()` call:

```
 string uri = PokeDexResultBase.BaseUrl + pokeRef.resource_uri;
```

The `PokeDexResultBase.BaseUrl` static string property would probably be better off as a static property of the `Pokedex` class, and then it would make `PokeDexResultBase` tightly coupled with `Pokedex`, which somehow makes sense.

Also, class `PokeDexResultBase` should be called `PokedexResultBase`, for consistency.

Comment: No need for Primitive Obsession. You can stick with `Uri`. You just need to use it consistently. `new Uri(Uri, Uri)` and `WebRequest.Create(Uri)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, i ended up with this approach in deserializing

```
// Pocos for deserializing
public class PocoAnswer
{ 
    PocoItem item {get; set;}
}

public class PocoItem
{
    String name {get; set; }
    DateTime birthday {get; set; }
}

// Model for binding
public ItemModel
{  
    public readonly PocoItem item; // I wish this to stay private, but json serializer cant get it then
    public ItemModel(PocoItem _item)
    { 
         item = _item;
    }

    [JsonIgnore] // No need to store runtime generated data
    public FormattedInfoString // This is used for binding 
    {
        get 
        {
            return String.Format("My amazing custom string contains name {0} and birth {1}, item.Name, item.Birthday.ToString("yy-mm");
        }
    }
}
```

And when i'm getting answer from the server, i'm pushing it into binded item

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PocoAnswer>(resultString);
BindableModel = new ItemModel(result.answer.item);
```

and then in xaml

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding BindableModel.FormattedInfoString} \>
```